# Unable to get "disallowSpacesInsideParentheses" to work

Tags: javascript, jscs

My .jscsrc file looks like below

```
{
    "preset": "wikimedia",
    "requireSpacesInsideArrayBrackets": null,
    "validateIndentation": 4,
    "disallowMultipleVarDecl": true,
    "disallowSpaceAfterObjectKeys": "ignoreMultiLine",
    "disallowSpacesInsideParentheses": { "only": [ "{", "}" ] }
}
```

But on running `jscs` over my code, it throws the following error in console

```
Missing space after opening round bracket at js/app.js :
    29 |                            windowScrollTimeout = null;
    30 |                            if (currentTopOffet < prevTopOffset) {
    31 |                                $('header').removeClass('mobile-hide');
----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

I also tried setting the value of `disallowSpacesInsideParentheses` to `true` but still no change in results. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Or is it that I am trying to solve my problem using wrong rule? Can somebody point me to the right rule set?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checking the source for [`disallowSpacesInsideParentheses`](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/blob/master/lib/rules/disallow-spaces-inside-parentheses.js), that rule won't throw the error you're seeing. It seems that your rule is conflicting with the [wikimedia presets rule](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/blob/master/presets/wikimedia.json#L29):

`"requireSpacesInsideParentheses": "all"`

[`requireSpacesInsideParentheses`](https://github.com/jscs-dev/node-jscs/blob/566d9e48e95b480e78217445b2bf3d102b2151b6/lib/rules/require-spaces-inside-parentheses.js#L113) seems to be the culprit, not any rule you've set, as it's the only rule which will throw that error. To overwrite the preset rule, according to the [docs](http://jscs.info/overview.html#presets) you'll need to set the rule to `null` in your `.jscsrc` file.

`"requireSpacesInsideParentheses": "null"`